# Bulk insert using format file

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert, bcp

My database named 'dictionary' have two column named 'column1' and 'column2'. Both can accept `NULL` value. The data-type of both columns is `INT`. Now I want to insert into only column2 from a text file using bcp. I made a format file. My format file is like that

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RECORD>
      <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="7"/>
      <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="24"/>
     </RECORD>
      <ROW>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="column2" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
      </ROW>
   </BCPFORMAT>
```

and my bulk statement is like

```
BULK INSERT dictionary
 FROM 'C:\Users\jka\Desktop\n.txt'
  WITH
  (
   FIELDTERMINATOR = '\n',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
   FORMATFILE = 'path to my format file.xml'
   )
```

But it didn't work? How can I solve this?

N:B:
My txt file looks like

```
123 
456
4101
```

......

One more question Edited:
i can fill one colum by this technique but when i fill another column from a text file like before from the 1st row. how can i do that ???

Comment: I don't see any Visual Studio, or C#

Comment: I assume `dictionary` is the name of a table not a database. Correct?

Comment: yeah dictionar is the name of the table @peterm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your format file is correct I believe you need to ditch `FIELDTERMINATOR` and `ROWTERMINATOR` from your `BULK INSERT`

```sql
BULK INSERT dictionary
FROM 'C:\Users\jka\Desktop\n.txt'
WITH (FORMATFILE = 'path to my format file.xml')
```

Also **make sure** that:

1. input file's encoding is correct. In your case most likely it should be ANSI and not UTF-8 or Unicode.
2. row terminator (which is second field terminator in your format file) is actually `\r\n` and not `\n`.

**UPDATE** Since you need to skip first column:

With an XML format file, there is no way to skip a column when you are importing directly into a table by using a `BULK INSERT` statement. In order to achieve desired result and still use XML format file you need to use `OPENROWSET(BULK...)` and provide explicit list of columns in the select list and in the target table.

So to insert data only to `column2` use:

```sql
INSERT INTO dictionary(column2)
SELECT column2
  FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\temp\infile1.txt',
       FORMATFILE='C:\temp\bulkfmt.xml') as t1;
```

If your data file has only one field your format file can look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RECORD>
        <FIELD ID="C1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="24"/>
    </RECORD>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="C1" NAME="column2" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
    </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Comment: may be my something wrong in my format file. but i dont understand.@peterm

Comment: Make sure that input file's encoding is correct. In your case most likely it should be ANSI and not UTF-8 or Unicode. row terminator (which is second field terminator in your format file) is actually \r\n and not `\n`. Your format file is working for me just fine.

Comment: But after then when i want to fill this null value[in column2] from another text file using same technique it didnt work??how can i do that??@peterm

Comment: To update NULL values with the data from another file later you'll need a way to correlate records in your table with rows in your second file. If number of rows in first and second file is the same then you can use identity column in your `dictionary` file, import second file to temp table with identity column, join both tables and update dictionary table with values from temp table. And finally drop temp table.

Comment: Better yet combine both files before `bulk insert` using Excel for example. Than you won't have those problems.

Comment: @user2029069 Did it help? Do you need more help with your **original** question?

Answer (score 0):

Your data file contains one field, so your format file should reflect that

```
<RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n"/>
</RECORD>
```

Comment: i can fill one colum by this technique but when i fill another column from a text file like before from the 1st row. how can i do that ???

Comment: Why are you asking the same questions as user2029069 and imon?

Comment: it was a mistake. so would you please help me about that??@phil

Comment: If you have two separate files presumably with the same number of items in each, bulk insert them into two tables both with identity columns.  Then combine the two tables into one by joining on the generated ids.